# Entity framework cascade one to zero or one relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have a Entity like below,

```
class User
    {
         public int Id {get;set;}
         public string Name {get;set;}

         public int? UserSecurityId {get;set;}
         public virtual UserSecurity UserSecurity {get;set;}

    }

class UserSecurity
{
  public int Id {get;set;}

  public int? AdminRoleId{get;set;}
  public virtual Admin AdminRole {get;set;}

  public int? ApproverRoleId {get;set;}
  public virtual TaskApprover ApproverRole {get;set;}
}

class Admin
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}

class TaskApprover
{ 
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I am using using entity framework 6.1.3
I need to delete the UserSecurity record when I delete the user from User table.

after gooling it, I found some thing like this,

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //// Cascade delete, The foreign key table records will be removed when its parent deleted.
            modelBuilder.Entity<EPDUser>().HasOptional(x => x.UserSecurity).WithOptionalDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
            modelBuilder.Entity<EPDUserSecurity>().HasOptional(x => x.AdminRole).WithOptionalDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
            modelBuilder.Entity<EPDUserSecurity>().HasOptional(x => x.ApproverRole).WithOptionalDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

And my repository code to delete the user is below,

```
 protected override void OnDelete(int id)
            {

                var user = EntitySet.Include(x=>x.UserSecurity).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
                EntitySet.Remove(user);
                DbContext.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            }
```

After saving the changes, the user record only gets deleted not the UserSecurity Record.

Kinldy help me out to delete the UserSecurity record when delete user.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're configuring your `EPDUser` to be the dependent entity in the relationship. So an `EPDUser` has a foreign key to the `EPDSecurity`, and will get deleted if you delete the associated `EPDSecurity`, but not the other way around. What you want to do is use `WithOptionalPrincipal`, which sets the entity being configured as the principal in the relationship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EPDUser>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.UserSecurity)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Comment: Hi Asad, You are rite. when I mentioned the above line, a new column named "EPDUser_ID" has been created and the corresponding user id has updated here. and when I delete the user also it deletes usersecurity tables.
Thanks for your reply.